# How to keyframe a movement using global transformation

Tags: animation

I created a Running animation in place, when I want to move my character to match the run, he has to move at different speeds whether he has a feet on the ground, or he is completely in the air. So I have 3 locations keyframe to make one full step. How can I duplicate that hole movement (the 3 locations keyframes) to make him run a long distance ? Because obviously if I just loop those keys he will just comeback to the first position every time. How may I get the location transformation to add upon his present location and not to be global ?

Comment: hello, could you please show some screenshots, even maybe share your file (only the armature)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Don't know if I understand the setup correctly, but could you not simply add modifiers in the _Graph Editor_, like _Cycles_ > _Repeat with Offset_? Isn't that what it's supposed to do, repeating a movement offsetting from where it is after the last movement?

Comment: @Chris, I always need several blend files each and every day, it's a kind of addiction, do I need rehab?

Comment: @moonboots: we can save money and we go together to that rehab...do you know a good one? :D

Comment: I only go to rehabs for stars in Hollywood

Answer (score 1):

Gordon is totally right but if you are a beginner it might be difficult to realize what he meant (and i couldn't solve that a few month ago either with just that sentence).

So here step by step:

1. find out the forward movement in graph editor:

[image]

yep, as beginner that's pretty tough to find out...but, if you think about it, the forward movement is the only one which increases over time. So if you make the graph smaller...

[image]

here we go!

Select one point, press N, click on "modifiers"

[image]

then "add modifiers" -> cycles -> looks promising

[image]

now change "repeat motion" to repeat with offset

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Of course my one sentence might not be helping a complete beginner... though I am actually a complete beginner on this. Never did any walk cycles myself because I'm doing no character animation. Just watched tutorials on this topic and assumed, people who are really doing this might have watched at least some tutorials on this topic as well and would know what I'm talking about :D